# Writing Greek text in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

Hello guys I'm trying so hard to make a document in greek with Rmarkdown, cause I dont want to learn all the Latex commands and it's very easy to actually make a document that seems like a Latex document with Rmarkdown. Really my only problem is the language. I've got so many errors and I've managed to handle them until now. Bellow I give you a simple example of what Rstudio produces. The problem is that it doesn't print any  greek letter but no error occured. I really dont know what's going on.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{fontspec}  
   - \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
   - \newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
   - \newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}

output:
   pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
---


{\gr{Αυτά είναι ελληνικά}}
```

I'm using tinytex in Rstudio with session info :

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service 
Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  
LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253    
LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  
LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     
datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    
rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6
[6] tools_3.5.0     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_0.12.18    
stringi_1.2.4   rmarkdown_1.10 
[11] knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.1   digest_0.6.15   
evaluate_0.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is crucial that you use a font that actually contains Greek glyphs. 
The following works for me when the input document is saved in UTF-8:

```
---
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
   - \newcommand{\en}[1]{{\selectlanguage{english}#1}}
   - \newcommand{\gr}[1]{{\selectlanguage{greek}#1}}
mainfont: GFS Didot
output:
   pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
---


\gr{Αυτά είναι ελληνικά}   \en{The gick brown fox jumps over the lazyy dog.}
```

I removed `\usepackage{fontspec}`, since that is done automatically when  `xelatex` is used. I have also updated your language switching commands to take an argument, since `pandoc` does not like the `{\command text}` style.

However, it would be more conventional to combine `xelatex` with `polyglossia` instead of `babel`. That's what `pandoc`does when you use the `lang` feature:

```
---
lang: el
mainfont: GFS Didot
output:
   pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
---


Αυτά είναι ελληνικά [the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]{.class lang="en"}

Αυτά είναι ελληνικά

::::: {.class lang="en"}

Here is a paragraph.

And another.

:::::

Αυτά είναι ελληνικά
```

Note that you might have to update `fontspec`/`mathspec`/`polyglossia` to avoid [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375517/xelatex-fontspec-hebrew-tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000).

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for your immediate response, and your advices are much appreciated. Well I tried to update the packages you said via the tlmgr_update() command (from tinytex package), I copy-pasted your last code and the error below is produced:

```
processing file: untitled.Rmd
output file: untitled.knit.md

! Package fontspec Error: The font "GFS Didot" cannot be 
found.

Error: Failed to compile untitled.tex. See untitled.log for 
more info.
Execution halted
```

I even did tlmgr_update("GFS") cause I saw that the font you used was from this package.

Comment: Anyway my friend it worked! I just used the Arial font and everything is ok! Thank you so much!