# Include a language besides English in a Rmarkdown -> LaTeX document

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

## Anyway to include a language besides English in Rmarkdown  *pdf_document*?

Consider using this *reprex*  to reproduce the problem.

````
---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ""
output:
  pdf_document:
    # latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_md: true
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
   # - \usepackage[arabic]{babel}
   - \usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

   # - \inputencoding{utf8}
   # - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
---
<!-- from https://rstudio.cloud/project/923892 -->

Uncomment the following code if your tinytex is not well configurated. Advisable to use in an Rstudio cloud project.

```{r}
# library(tinytex)
# options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
# options(tinytex.clean = FALSE)
# if (!dir.exists('~/.TinyTeX')) {
#   install_tinytex()
# }
# 
# Sys.getenv("PATH")

```

h

ل

dtthf

dgfافق
````

I wish to knit a document that includes English and Arabic text. The Arabic text  is considered Unicode characters and execution halts. Using either of latex engines *xelatex* or *lualatex* renders the document successfully, but the Arabic/unicode characters are not rendered; they are simply ignored.

From this Rstudio community topic( [Latex language package installation not working - RStudio Cloud - RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/latex-language-package-installation-not-working/51596/8)), it seems that there is a problem with defining languages in `tinytex`.  A solution offered was to include:

```
header-includes:
     \usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
```

in the YAML header, to use the Icelandic locale provided by the [CTAN: Package babel](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel) project for multilingual LaTeX support. Using:

```
header-includes:
     \usepackage[arabic]{babel}
```

renders Arabic characters perfectly, but renders only Arabic. English letters are converted to Arabic ones, even the R code itself. From the babel support, you can use this:

```
header-includes:

     \usepackage[arabic, english]{babel}
```

to declare you are using both English and Arabic, with the last one called (in this case, English) being the default language. However, I get this error: **`! LaTeX Error: Command \lam unavailable in encoding T1.`** The \lam command corresponds to the Arabic letter, lam ( ل ),  it just happens to be the first Arabic letter in the text. I tried to use *xelatex*, I tried to change the encoding into *utf8*, but none of these solved the solution.

I have no prior LaTeX knowledge so these encoding and multilingual topics seem to difficult for me. The main question is: how to successfully knit a bilingual rmarkdown document, especially English-Arabic document? Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: Look there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496941/how-to-write-in-english-in-an-arabic-text

Comment: Dear @manro , sorry for the delay!
 I tried what the link you mentioned suggests (look below) but still the same problem. 
---
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  - \usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
  - \usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
  - \newcommand{\ab}{\selectlanguage{arabic}}
  - \newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
```

Comment: From (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419058/writing-greek-text-in-rmarkdown) and (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539913/fonts-for-rmarkdown-document), it seems like I have to change the font to a font that actually includes Arabic characters. Using `[LAE, T1]{fontenc}` doesn't solve anything. I tried the `fontspec` package but I can't find a OpenType font that provides Arabic and English characters. You have any experience with that?

Comment: Hm, try to read about package ```polyglossia``` https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_polyglossia_and_fontspec

Comment: You could try to set `lang: ar` in the metadata and use `[some English text]{lang=en}` to mark other text. You may also have manually add `[text]{dir="rtl"}` or `dir="ltr"` here and there to adjust the text direction.

Comment: @manro, I tried the following under the `xelatex` engine:
```
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{polyglossia}
  - \setdefaultlanguage{english}
  - \setotherlanguage{arabic}
  - \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
````
I get the same output as when nothing is put in the header of the tex: English is rendered, Arabic is ignored.

Comment: @manro
If you **set the main language to be Arabic** and the other language to be English, you get no output at all! You get `! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font latinmodern-math.otf(3) does not contain the "Arabic" script!     (polyglossia) Please define \arabicfont with \newfontfamily command.` Although I defined the Arabic font for Arabic script properly!

There seems to be a problem with setting the main language to Arabic.

Comment: @tarleb
I get Arabic characters rendered when I use xelatex engine with a mainfont that understands Arabic scripts. However, the rendered text is in wrong direction, RTL, and the letters within each word aren't witten as they are a part of the same word, they are just written side-by-side. Unfortunately, using `[text](lang=ar)` and `[text](dir="rtl")` doesn't help with it. This reprex in reproduces the problem on my Windows OS:

````
---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ""
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Arial

---
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
````

Comment: Editing last comment: `[text]{dir="rtl"}`  works! Words are aligned as they should. However, How do I overcome the problem of bad letter-to-letter junctions? To make it clear to you, instead of getting the sentence _بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم_و I get [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w1zuFTRZv3639ytJa1MDitz58kftXseB/view?usp=sharing).  Any help?

Comment: Solved! To render a bilingual Arabic-English Rmarkdown -> LaTeX document smoothly, you need `xelatex`, `polyglossia`, and a `mainfont`! No LaTeX lines needed in the preamable needed, Pandoc YAML variables will do it all. Check the code in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397830/auto-align-text-for-a-bilingual-rmarkdown-latex-document). Thanks a lot @manro and @tarleb .

Comment: I gave you "+1" for the nice effort. Working with another from English locale is always torment.

Comment: @HossamGhorab you could write an answer to your own question, that would make it easier for others to find the answer (and would probably get you some points, too).

Comment: Thanks @tarleb ! I shall post a the solution and maybe add it to the post itself once the mis-alignment problem is solved.